# Error when calling ASP.NET web services from Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services

I'm trying to call a ASP.NET web service from Javascript, and it won't recognize the Web Method, even when I fully qualify the name, I'm trying to figure out what is wrong.

Here is the part of my web.config file:

```
<httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Here is my web service declarations

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SavingService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static void SaveToDB(string runCode, string container, 
        string productType, string inspector, string[][] scoregrid, string notes)
```

and here is the javascript (QCApp4 is my project's namespace):

```
function PrepToSave()
{
    ....
    QCApp4.SavingService.SaveToDB(codev, containerv, prodtype, inspector, scoregrid, notes);
}
```

scoregrid is declared on the js side as a jagged 2d array using the Array() command. That was the only worry I had with regard to the parameters of the web service.

And here is the service reference:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="scriptmng" runat="server">
<Services>
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/SavingService.asmx" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I get errors whether I call the web method directly, or call it like SavingService.SaveToDB, or with the full Qualifiers. The error I get says that SaveToDB is not defined. SavingService is not defined, QCApp4 is not defined, depending on what the first part of the qualified name is entered as.

Am I missing something? Is there something I've set incorrectly?

It turns out I had made my WebMethod static, of course now I'm getting an error in the error console of:

Error: [Exception... "'Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'SaveToDB' failed with the following error: System.NullReferenceException-- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when calling method: [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]"  nsresult: "0x8057001c (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)"  location: ""  data: no]

Comment: can you provide the actual calling getting made, such as the URL, and also the error?  Is it a 500 or 404 error?

Comment: It isn't an error that's visible in the browser. I only found out about it using Firefox's Error console. But the web method isn't being called as a result. 

The error in Error Console says:
Error: QCApp4 is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:2507/Sheet.aspx
Line: 153

Comment: What do you mean by the actual calling? I'm calling a Web Method in the same project as the web page calling from. According to what I've read I can just make the call as if I was calling a Javascript function. Am I incorrect in that assumption?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `InlineScript` attribute on the `ServiceReference` element, it'll write out the JavaScript methods inline with the HTML so you can see exactly what you need to call or if you're calling the wrong thing:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/SavingService.asmx" InlineScript="true" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

I screwed up two things with this. I went back and found the video I had previously watched on setting these web services up.

I realized, I had accidentally made the web method static, and also forgotten to add the callback method parameters. Once I added a on complete and an on error handler, it worked fine, no errors in the Error Console.